# How to close BufferedWriter after waiting for its write completion

Tags: java

My `JavafX` application is recognizing speech and converting it to text (which I log to a text file using an ExecutorService for every write process), as soon as I close the `stage` I call a method from my Main Thread to close the `BufferedWriter`.

**Listener Thread Snippet (shares Observer - Observable pattern with Main):**

```
@Override
public void stopSTT() {
    try {
        recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync().get();
        speechLogger.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**SpeechLogger:**

```
private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

public SpeechLogger(String filename){
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
        this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void log(String recognized){
    try {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.format("[%s: %s] %s\n","INFO",new Date(),recognized));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void log(String recognized, String translation){
    try {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.format("[INFO %s] [ORIGINAL] %s [TRANSLATED] %s\n", new Date(),recognized,translation));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close(){
    try{
        bufferedWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Buffered writer closed...");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Writing process:**

```
 SpeechLogger speechLogger = new SpeechLogger();
 executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("    WRITING to file...");
                            speechLogger.log(e.getResult().getText());
                        }
                    });
```

I call `stopSTT` from my `Main` thread. However when I close it and the `bufferedWriter` is still writing, what is the case IMO,  I get the following Error output:

```
WRITING to file...
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Session stopped event.
at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:107)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:224)
at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
at speechToText.logic.SpeechLogger.log(SpeechLogger.java:23)
at speechToText.logic.SpeechServiceOneLang$1.run(SpeechServiceOneLang.java:56)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: When you close the stream, before call `close()` you must be call `flush()`, I think this is teh problem

Comment: Synchronize on the `BufferedWriter` for every method call on it if you are using it from multiple threads. The problem with this code is that you *aren't* waiting for anything concurrent to finish.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo No. `close()` calls `flush()`. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @user207421 my fault, sorry

Comment: @JBNizet works like a charm, thank you :) You may write this comment as answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shut down the executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--), then [await for its termination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), then finally close the logger.